# $query = "INSERT INTO

Tags: php, insert

I'm still getting used to PHP and what it can do. I have designed a `register.php` page. I have it working, however it is only posting empty fields into the table.

This is the code I am using:

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO users (`id`, `fname`, `lname`, `username`, `email`, `password`)
    VALUES ('', '".$fname."','".$lname."','".$username."','".$email."','".$password."')";
```

The data I post to the database isn't being entered, but blank fields are, so something is happening.

I tried to run:

```
echo `$query`;
```

And this is what I get from the output:

```
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `fname`, `lname`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('', '','','','','')
```

Any hint, tips or help is on this problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your surrounding code, specifically the area where you define `$fname, $lname, $username, $email,` and `$password`.

Comment: Quick guess: `$fname`, `$lname`, `$username`, `$email` and `$password` are all empty.

Comment: You're missing the code that matters.

Comment: Your `$query` is set fine. How are you assigning the variables `$fname`, `$lname`, `$username`, `$email`, `$password`? Please include that code.

Comment: this is the surounding code....... <?php

 
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {   
   
   
   // if everything if ok
  
   //Register the user in the database
   require_once ('mysql.php'); //connect to the database
   
   //add the info to the database
   $query = "INSERT INTO users (`id`, `fname`, `lname`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('', '".$fname."','".$lname."','".$username."','".$email."','".$password."')";
   echo $query;
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); //run the query.
   if ($result)
   {
?>

Comment: Be warned: you don't know nearly enough about php/mysql to have the word "password" ever show up in your code. Don't try to make secure websites if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

For each of those fields, assign them before using them in the query if you are not already:

```
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
```

The `mysql_real_escape_string` function helps prevent against SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

When doing an insert and not passing a specific ID, it is best to use `NULL` instead of leaving empty space with a comma... Infact, I am unsure if that is valid syntax at all

Comment: The issue is that he wants to insert data but the variables don't contain any - not that he is trying to insert blank records.

Comment: He's talking about the ID field only, which usually is AI so you don't need to use it in your query, as it gets automatically inserted

Comment: My comment was regarding the start of his `VALUES()` being legitimately empty. No variable at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `method` attribute on your HTML form that is submitting the data is set to either `post` or `get`.

Assuming your variable names match field names in the form, then instead of using `$fname` etc, address your data as `$_POST['fname']` or `$_GET['fname']` depending on the `action` of your HTML form

Answer (score 0):

May be you think that register_globals is equal 'on' ? ))

But this directive is depricated. Show your code before this query. You have to set your variables ($lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']))...

Comment: this is the code before the INSERT bit $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
   $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
   $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
   $repeatpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['repeatpassword']);

   // if everything if ok
  
   //Register the user in the database
   require_once ('mysql.php'); //connect to the database